# Operator `<=' cannot be applied to operands of type `VictoryCountdown' and `int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class VictoryCountdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float victoryCountdown = 300.0f;
    public Text startText;


    void Update()
    {
        victoryCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        startText.text = "Survive until dawn!: " + (victoryCountdown).ToString("0");

    }
}

/////////// 2nd Script below ///////////////////

using UnityEngine;

public class VictoryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VictoryCountdown victoryCountdown;


    Animator anim;


    void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (victoryCountdown <= 0)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Victory");
        }
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm a beginning student so this may be an obvious error. I need to create a countdown timer to end a game. I believe that I have everything working, but ran into this issue at the final hour.

The first script creates a timer and then counts down to 0. The second script triggers the victory screen animation. Unity is returning the error:

> Operator `<=' cannot be applied to operands of type`VictoryCountdown'
>   and `int

I made some progress, but hit this hurdle and was hoping someone more experienced could tell me what I have done wrong.

Comment: Ummm....`victoryCountdown.victoryCountdown`

Comment: When you want to use operators _(e.g. `<=`)_ with a class, you need to define them. But in this simple case I would recommend you to use a property or function in `VictoryCountdown` class, _(e.g. `bool Elapsed() {  return (victoryCountdown <= 0f); }`)_ Members of classes should be private and should not be accessed outside of their own class.

Comment: Note about the [tag:visual-studio] tag: if you read the description, it says *"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*

Answer (score 4):

You have a problematic naming convention. Also, you are trying to compare the
VictoryCountDown object with an int and that's not possible.

you can easily fix it like this. But it'll look like a mess...

```
    if (victoryCountdown.victoryCountdown <= 0)
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Victory");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are defining an object of type VictoryCountdown, and you are naming that object victoryCountdown. Your comparison isn't accessing the class variable victoryCountdown, but the object. To get the variable, you have to do something like victoryCountdown.victoryCountdown, where you are accessing the variable through an instance of the class (though I would recommend changing the name of the class instance to avoid this confusion).

I would also note that the variable you want is a float and 0 is an int, so that comparison might not work as well (I'm not as familiar with how C# handles this kind of type disparity)